# Pull amazon managed Kafka cluster metrics to amazon managed service for Prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, prometheus, monitoring, aws-msk

I have an Amazon `MSK` cluster (Amazon managed service for Kafka) with `OpenMonitoring` enabled (`JMX` and `Node exporter` both). I also have a `Workspace` created under the `Amazon managed service for Prometheus` (AMP).

How to pull the metrics from MSK cluster to AMP workspace?

I have gone through [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/open-monitoring.html) in Amazon docs itself, but this explains the normal Prometheus (with `EKS` and `EC2` where Prometheus server's running), not the managed one. Also, checked some Youtube videos, but not finding anything which covers `MSK with AMP`. Please help with the steps and do let me know if need more information.

Thanks!